# msmtp directory for sent mail

Tags: email, mutt, msmtp

After sending message with `msmtp -a account1` (integrated with mutt) sended message appears in ~/sent/new, how can I  change this directory?

.msmtprc:

```
account account1
host smtp.gmail.com
port 587
protocol smtp
auth on
from 
user 
password 
tls on
tls_nocertcheck
```

Answer (score 0):

Not msmtp put mail in ~/sent, but mutt. 
You need to provide `record` variable, and mutt will put sent mail into it, like so:

```
set record = "+account/sent"
```